# How to remove a snapper config when getting error “deleting snapshot failed”?

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot

I am using snapper to take snapshots of btrfs volumes. I have one for `/var` as well, but decided that I want to get rid of it. It corresponds to the `_var` snapper config. I can't manage to do this, because when I say `# snapper -v -c _var delete-config`, I get the following error:

```
Deleting config failed (deleting snapshot failed).
```

All but the ‘active’ snapshot have been deleted, however.

I have restarted my laptop and unmounted the `/var/.snapshot` volume, to no avail.

When I say `snapper -c _var list`, I get:

```
 # | Type   | Pre # | Date | User | Cleanup | Description | Userdata
---+--------+-------+------+------+---------+-------------+---------
0  | single |       |      | root |         | current     |
```

Can anyone help me properly remove this snapper config?

(N.B.: For now, I've set all automatic snapshotting (timeline,…) off in the config.)

Answer (score 1):

I could manage to remove a snapper config for which the `.snapshots` folder had been deleted by (on Debian):

- removing the config file from /etc/snapper/configs/
- removing the config name from /etc/default/snapper

Source: https://sobrelinux.info/questions/505676/how-do-i-reinstall-enable-snapper

Comment: This is an approach that circumvents snapper, I have the impression, but anyway, it seems to do the job. BTW: for me the second file was `/etc/conf.d/snapper`.

Comment: Indeed. I'd also prefer something more clean but it is the only way I found to be working. Maybe you should check that there is nothing left in the .snapshots folder.